# esp32 spi library, how read a mcp23s08 register

Tags: pins, spi, esp32

thanks for any help
I need to read a gpio expander mcp23s08 set as 8 bits input.
my code write correctly (I believe) the setup register using SPI library, with the enclosed example modified.
But I do not understand how read a gpio register (0x09)
code (with the read out routine wrong:

```
#define GPIO_SEL_pin 14                         // D14 = MCP23S08 GPIO SPI select pin
#define SCLK 18                                 // D18 SPI SCLK 
#define MISO 19                                 // D19 SPI MISO
#define MOSI 23                                 // D23 SPI MOSI

#include <SPI.h>

uint8_t keyboard;

static const int spiClk = 1000000; // 1 MHz

//uninitalised pointers to SPI objects
SPIClass * mcp23s08 = NULL;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(GPIO_SEL_pin, OUTPUT);                     //MCP23S08 SPI select pin
  digitalWrite(GPIO_SEL_pin, HIGH);                  //pull ss high to disable data transfer
  mcp23s08 = new SPIClass(VSPI);
  mcp23s08->begin(SCLK, MISO, MOSI, GPIO_SEL_pin);   //SCLK, MISO, MOSI, SS
  mcp23s08SetUp();
  delay(1);

}

void loop() {
  keyboard = mcp23s08Read();
  Serial.println (keyboard);
  delay(100);
}

// ================================== routines =================================
void mcp23s08SetUp( void ) {
  uint8_t dev_adr  = 0x40;                          // MCP23S08 address 0; R/W = write
  uint8_t reg_adr  = 0x00;                          // MCP23S08 IODIR register
  uint8_t reg_data = 0xFF;                          // pin configured as input

  digitalWrite(GPIO_SEL_pin, LOW);                 //pull SS slow to prep other end for transfer
// ============================= MCP3S08 pin as input ==============================
  mcp23s08->beginTransaction(SPISettings(spiClk, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
  mcp23s08->transfer(dev_adr);  
  mcp23s08->transfer(reg_adr);  
  mcp23s08->transfer(reg_data);  
  mcp23s08->endTransaction();

  reg_adr  = 0x01;                                 // MCP23S08 IPOL register
  reg_data = 0xFF;                                 // invert input polarity
// ============================= MCP3S08 invert input ==============================
  mcp23s08->beginTransaction(SPISettings(spiClk, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
  mcp23s08->transfer(dev_adr);  
  mcp23s08->transfer(reg_adr);  
  mcp23s08->transfer(reg_data);  
  mcp23s08->endTransaction();

  reg_adr  = 0x06;                                 // MCP23S08 GPPU pull-up register
  reg_data = 0xFF;                                 // set pull-up register
// ============================= MCP3S08 pullup resistor ==============================
  mcp23s08->beginTransaction(SPISettings(spiClk, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
  mcp23s08->transfer(dev_adr);  
  mcp23s08->transfer(reg_adr);  
  mcp23s08->transfer(reg_data);  
  mcp23s08->endTransaction();

  digitalWrite(GPIO_SEL_pin, HIGH);                //pull ss high to signify end of data transfer
}

uint8_t mcp23s08Read ( void ) {
  uint8_t dev_adr  = 0x41;                          // MCP23S08 address 0; R/W = read
  uint8_t reg_adr  = 0x09;                          // MCP23S08 GPIO register
  uint8_t reg_data;                                 // GPIO register
  mcp23s08->beginTransaction(SPISettings(spiClk, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
  mcp23s08->transfer(dev_adr);  
  mcp23s08->transfer(reg_adr);  
  reg_data = mcp23s08->transfer(0x00);  
  mcp23s08->endTransaction(); 
  return reg_data; 
}
```

Comment: Why do you toggle SS inside mcp23s08SetUp() function and NOT inside mcp23s08Read()?
I don't remember if SS pin is managed by SPI Arduino library, but you can try it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just forgot to toggle the ss pin.

Comment: Hi @Angelo Gilin Maggiora if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. @leoc7 could you tell me where is the check-mark button? I did not find in the page. Sorry, I am a newbe

Comment: Read answer of this question in order to know how to accept an answer. :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I, hopefully, did it. Isn't it

Comment: I would submint the full working example of setting up and readout of GPIO expander MCP23S08 using esp32 and SPI bus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to toggle SS pin in `mcp23s08Read()` function.

```
 uint8_t mcp23s08Read ( void ) {
      ----> digitalWrite(GPIO_SEL_pin, LOW);                 //pull SS slow to prep other end for transfer
      uint8_t dev_adr  = 0x41;                          // MCP23S08 address 0; R/W = read
      uint8_t reg_adr  = 0x09;                          // MCP23S08 GPIO register
      uint8_t reg_data;                                 // GPIO register
      mcp23s08->beginTransaction(SPISettings(spiClk, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
      mcp23s08->transfer(dev_adr);  
      mcp23s08->transfer(reg_adr);  
      reg_data = mcp23s08->transfer(0x00);  
      mcp23s08->endTransaction(); 
      ----> digitalWrite(GPIO_SEL_pin, HIGH);                //pull ss high to signify end of data transfer
      return reg_data; 
    }
```